# Infinitesimal transformation of a state function

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems

I am reading the paper [*Hamilton's Principle and the Conservation Theorems of Mathematical Physics*](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.23.253) by E. L. Hill.

In section III, he writes the infinitesimal transformation of the *independent variables* $x^k$ as:

$x^{\prime k}=x^{k}+\delta x^{k}\quad(3a)$

where $\delta x^{k}\equiv\lambda\xi^{k}(x)$, $\xi$ is an arbitrary function. Then, he writes the infinitesimal transformation of the *state functions* (dependent variables) as:

$\psi^{\prime\alpha}(x^{\prime})=\psi^{\alpha}(x)+\delta\psi^{\alpha}(x)\quad(3b)$

---

**My question is:** why in the right hand of equation $(3b)$ the functions are dependent of $x$ and not $x^\prime$?

I understand that the variations $\delta\psi^{\alpha}$ may be written as dependent of $x$ or $x^\prime$ because of the Taylor expansion that can be made on them (footnote 8). But, why $\psi^{\alpha}(x)$ appears in the transfromation instead of $\psi^{\alpha}(x^\prime)$?

Comment: Under the transformation of $x$, the function also changes: if you like, $\psi^\alpha(x)$ is transformed to some new $\psi_{new}(x')$, i.e. the new (transformed) function at the transformed location. The point is that this new object is equal to the old object plus a suitable change, which includes information about the transformation of $x$.

You *can* write $\psi^\alpha(x)$ on the right hand side of your equation as $\psi^\alpha(x'-\delta x)$ and Taylor expand that to get the particular kind of form you want. 
But the way its written is the way such a transformation is usually presented.

Comment: Ok, that helps. Would it be wrong writing the equation like $\psi^{\prime}(x^\prime)=\psi(x+\delta x)+\delta\psi(x+\delta x)$? Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: Start from (3a) and note that (3b) is in a way the definition of $\psi'^\alpha(x')$, which dictates what $\delta\psi^\alpha(x)$ will be. But you could write something else, and that would just give you a more complicated looking equation to work with. Look at Milou's cleaner derivation of this in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've replaced $x^\prime$ by $x+\delta x$, $\quad$ so

$\psi^{\prime\alpha}(x')=\psi^{\prime \alpha}(x+\delta x)=\psi^{\prime\alpha}(x)+\delta\psi^{\prime\alpha}(x)=\psi^{\alpha}(x)+\delta\psi^{\alpha}(x)$

Comment: I don't see why the last step is true, isn't it saying that the state function is invariant? ($\psi^\prime = \psi$)

Comment: So, you can't write $\psi'$ and $\psi$ in isolation, suppressing the functional dependence. Note that the function and the independent variable both change. So it makes no sense to even write $\psi' = \psi$. You must compare $\psi'(x')$ with $\psi(x)$ or $\psi(x)$ with $\psi'(x)$. These are different things!

Comment: @Saavestro, leastraction is totally right.  For example, $\psi^\prime(x^\prime)$ is obviously different than $\psi^\prime(x)$. To see how $\psi^\prime(x)$ is equal to $\psi(x)$, you can do the same simple method that is in my answer: the "prime" means a transformation which is in this case from x to x! so you replace x by x (there's no $\delta$ here) and simply you get $\psi^\prime(x)=\psi(x)$

Comment: @Saavestro, just for fun,  you can also write $\psi^ {\prime \alpha}(x^\prime)=\psi^\alpha(x^\prime)=\psi^\alpha(x+\delta x)=\psi^\alpha(x)+\delta \psi^\alpha(x)$.

Comment: @Saavestro, I'm not able to edit my first comment, but I wanted to say (in the first line) that $\psi^\prime (x^\prime)$ is different than $\psi(x)$ (not  $\psi^\prime (x)$ as written in the comment)

Comment: @Milou Ok, I think that it is clear now that $\psi^{prime\alpha}(x)=\psi^{\alpha}(x)$. But now I have doubt with what would mean the variation $\delta_{*}\psi^{\alpha}(x^\prime)=\psi^{\prime\alpha}(x^\prime)-\psi^{\alpha}(x^\prime)$ (equation $(10')$ from the paper)...

Comment: I 'm sorry I have no access to the paper. I'm trying to help you but now i have no answer because I have forgotten how things work here. I hope that someone tells you the answer, and if I remember I'll comment later. sorry!